# error handling inside ngrx effects

Tags: ngrx-effects, rxjs6

I know there are examples on effect error handling all over the net but in my case I am not calling an http service which returns an observable like 99% of the examples I have found, so I am at a loss for structuring these operators to get the desired effect.

I need to move my catchError() into my switchMap()

```
switchMap( ( [ routerState, state ] ) => {

    const tenantKey = routerState.params[ 'tenantKey' ];
    if ( state ) {
      if ( state.tenant && state.tenant.id === tenantKey ) {
        return of( { type: '[TenantContext] Tenant Context Check Valid', payload: state.tenant } );
      } else {
        return of( new LoadContextAction( tenantKey ) );
      }

    } else {
      return of( new LoadContextAction( tenantKey ) );
    }

  } ),
  catchError( ( err ) => {
    return of( { type: '[TenantContext] Error', payload: err } );
  } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing switchMap with map.

```
map( ( [ routerState, state ] ) => {
  const tenantKey = routerState.params[ 'tenantKey' ];
  if ( state ) {
    if ( state && state.id === tenantKey ) {
      return {
        type: '[TenantClubContext] Tenant Context Check Valid',
        payload: state
      };
    } else {
      return new LoadContextAction( tenantKey );
    }
  } else {
    return new LoadContextAction( tenantKey );
  }
} ),
catchError( err => {
  return of( { type: '[TenantClubContext] Error', payload: err } );
} )
```